# Haskell: Возможно ли апплицировать элементы списка длины n к функции?

Tags: функции, типы, haskell

Сложилась такая ситуация:

- Есть функция `fn :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool`.
- Есть список, состоящий из списков возможных значений аргументов функции `fn`: `[[False, False, False], ... , [True, True, True]]` (генерируется по количеству аргументов функции)

Я хочу достичь чего-то вроде "starred expression" в Python: `fn(*[a,b,...,z]) == fn(a,b,...,z)` 
и делаю как-то так, чтобы получить значения функции для всех "аргументных" списков: `map (t $ fn) [[False, False, False], [True, True, True]]`, где `t f [x,y,z] = f x y z`.

Проблема в том, что аргументов у `fn` может быть не три, а больше или меньше. Как, соответственно, и элементов в "аргументных" списках.

Как реализовать функцию `t`, чтобы та принимала вторым аргументом список с переменным количеством элементов? Заранее спасибо!

**Edit**:

Я дошел до идеального решения, казалось бы: `foldl a (\x -> \y -> \z -> z) [1,2,3]`, где `a = \f -> \x -> f x`.
Проведём бета-редукцию:

1. `a (\x -> \y -> \z -> z) 1` == `(\x -> (\t -> \y -> \z -> z) x) 1` == `\y -> \z -> z`
2. `a (\y -> \z -> z) 2` == `(\x -> (\y -> \z -> z) x) 2` == `\z -> z`
3. `a (\z -> z) 3` == `(\x -> (\z -> z) x) 3` == `3`

Но:

```
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 ~ t0 -> t0
      Expected type: (t0 -> t0 -> t0 -> t0) -> t0 -> t0 -> t0 -> t0 -> t0
        Actual type: (t0 -> t0 -> t0 -> t0 -> t0)
                     -> t0 -> t0 -> t0 -> t0 -> t0
    • In the first argument of ‘foldl’, namely ‘a’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘foldl a (\ x -> \ y -> \ z -> z) [1, 2, 3]’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘show $ foldl a (\ x -> \ y -> \ z -> z) [1, 2, 3]’
```

ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: Что должно происходить если в списке окажется не три элемента?

Comment: Эти "не три" элемента должны будут встать в fn в качестве аргументов. Допустим, "не три" -- это два. Тогда fn будет Bool -> Bool -> Bool и случайно выбранный "аргументный" список будет [False, True]. И тогда: t fn [False, True] вернёт условное True.

Comment: По сути, в случае, когда элемента два, t -- это uncurry, но для списка. Я хочу выяснить, возможно ли сделать "резиновый" uncurry.

Comment: То есть вы хотите сказать, что у функции `t` тип первого аргумента должен зависеть от значения второго? (обратите внимание: не от _типа_ второго аргумента, а от его _значения_)

Comment: Нет, гарантируется, что количество аргументов в функции и количество элементов в списке будут совпадать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Резиновый" `curry` сделать конечно можно. Ваш пример с `foldl` не работает, потому что результат каждой итерации должен быть одного и того же типа, а у вас типы разные: первая итерация `Bool -> Bool -> Bool`, вторая `Bool -> Bool`, третья `Bool`.

Но в Хаскелле есть механизм, позволяющий создавать функции с переменными типами аргументов. Этот механизм - классы.

```
class CallWithBoolList f where
    t :: f -> [Bool] -> Bool
```

Здесь `f` - это тип функции, которую вы хотите вызвать с аргументами из списка, а `t` - это ваша искомая функция. Её первый параметр - это функция `f`, второй параметр - список аргументов, а возвращает она результат вызова `f` с этими аргументами.

Первый случай - базовый: пустой список аргументов. В этом случае тип функции `f` вырождается просто в `Bool`. Ведь функция без аргументов - это просто значение. Запишем:

```
instance CallWithBoolList Bool where
    t b [] = b
    t _ _ = error "Слишком много аргументов"
```

Обратите внимание, что если передать сюда не пустой список, будет вызвана ошибка. К этому я ещё вернусь.

Второй случай - рекурсивный: список аргументов, состоящий из головы и хвоста. В этом случае тип функции `f` должен быть `Bool -> a`, где `Bool` - это её первый аргумент, а `a` - это "остаток" функции, то есть функция, которая ожидает все аргументы кроме первого, и потом возвращает значение. Запишем:

```
instance CallWithBoolList a => CallWithBoolList (Bool -> a) where
    t f (x:xs) = t (f x) xs
    t _ [] = error "недостаточно аргументов"
```

Здесь функция `t` передаёт первый аргумент ("голову" списка) в функцию `f`, та возвращает "остаток функции", и он затем передаётся в "предыдущую" версию функции `t` вместе с остальными аргументами ("хвостом" списка).

Проверим как это работает:

```
f1 x = not x
f2 x y = x && y
f3 x y z = x && y && z
f4 x y z w = x && y || z && w

main = do
    print $ t f1 [True] -- выводит False
    print $ t f2 [True, False] -- выводит False
    print $ t f3 [True, False, True] -- выводит False
    print $ t f4 [True, True, False, False] -- выводит True
    print $ t f1 [True, False] -- ошибка: слишком много аргументов
```

---

Этот подход можно обобщить на любой тип, не только `Bool`. Класс и его реализации при этом будут выглядеть так:

```
class CallWithList f res where
    t' :: f -> [res] -> res

instance CallWithList res res where
    t' res [] = res
    t' _ _ = error "слишком много аргументов"

instance CallWithList f res => CallWithList (res -> f) res where
    t' f (x:xs) = t' (f x) xs
    t' _ [] = error "недостаточно аргументов"
```

Единственное отличие - это дополнительная переменная `res`, которая присутствует в классе и реализациях, заменяя тип `Bool`.

---

Однако, глядя на ваши комментарии, я сомневаюсь, что это именно то, чего вы искали. В частности, обратите внимание, что в моей реализации, если вызвать функцию `t` с "неправльным" количеством аргументов, она выдаёт ошибку. Но на мой вопрос в комментариях о том, что должно происходить в таком случае, вы ответили:

> Эти "не три" элемента должны будут встать в `fn` в качестве аргументов. Допустим, "не три" -- это два. Тогда `fn` будет `Bool -> Bool -> Bool`

Это непонятно. Например, как должна работать вот такая программа:

```
main = do
    let f x y z = x && y && z
    print $ t f [True, False]
```

В моей реализации она выдаст ошибку во время выполнения. А чего ожидаете вы?

Допустим, вы скажете, что такая программа не должна компилироваться. Хорошо, тогда пусть список аргументов вводит пользователь:

```
main = do
    let f x y z = x && y && z
    args <- read <$> readLine
    print $ t f args
```

Что тогда? Непонятно.

Если вы уточните, что именно вы ожидаете увидеть, возможно я смогу предложить лучшее решение.

Comment: Нет-нет, ваша реализация с классами -- это именно то, что мне было нужно. Спасибо огромное! Отмечу, что для работы кода `t'` нужны расширения FlexibleInstances и MultiParamTypeClasses.